# group by with variable rows from other table, sql server

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have 3 result set as-

@userIDs -

```
 UserID
   1
   2
```

@crsIDs -

```
 CurriculumID
    1
    2
```

@result

```
UserID  CurriculumID FailOrPass
  1          1       1
  2          1       0
  1          2       0
  2          2       0
```

there are 2 Users and 2 Curriculum, 1 mean pass and 0 means fail (FailOrPass), now i want that how many users are passed and how many failed. To pass users must pass in each curriculum otherwise he will fail. In the above example the output can be -

```
UserID    FailOrPass
  1           0
  2           0
```

since none of the user pass in all curriculums.

I am getting difficulty in grouping the @result table over @crsIDs, further for calculating overall FailOrPass my idea is to group by @result table over @crsIDs and @userIDs and get the min value for FailOrPass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just go to the @result table and use:

```
 select userId, min(FailOrPass) as FailOrPass
 from @result
 group by userId
```

The `min()` function will return 0 if any values are 0.

Comment: well, how about the crsIDs ? each user must be grouped by all crsIDs values also ?

Comment: @user1509581 . . . Your question seems unclear about whether it is for all courses or all courses within a curriculum.  For the latter, you would add `curriculum` to the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UserID, FailOrPass = MIN(FailOrPass)
FROM @Result
GROUP BY UserID
```

should return the expected output.

Comment: well, how about the crsIDs ? each user must be grouped by all crsIDs values also ? since crsIDs may have variable records ?